# Google Cloud Auto ML Vision Permission Denied

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-automl, automl

I have a weird situation in Google Cloud Platform Auto ML Vision API. When I do API request it always throws an error that says PERMISSION DENIED, please see sample error response below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Here is what I did so far:

1. Created Service Account and download json file that contains the service account keys.
2. Enabled AutoML Editor and AutoML Admin for my service account.
3. Integrated the predict rest api and generate bearer token using the code below:

   ```
    var credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
       .fromStream(context.assets.open("service_account_key.json"))
       .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"))
   credentials.refreshIfExpired()
   val accesstoken = credentials.accessToken
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add these scopes to your credentials:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform 
 #(View and manage your data across Google Cloud Platform services)


 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision
 #(Apply machine learning models)
```

Also can you run this command to test if your service account has the wright permissions. If this works then you have an issue on your code.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/models
```

Comment: After running the command u mentioned it throws an error

"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the automl.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: because you have to authenticate with the service account you created. The error message says you authenticate with user credentials. Please replace ACCOUNT with service account you created and KEY_FILE with the key.json file for this service account.

Comment: How to properly authenticate using service account? I already have the key.json and directly loading it in the code from the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new service account in "IAM & Admin" and download a new JSON key file (then update your code to reflect the new file name).

I just spent 12 hours troubleshooting this and tried every possible solution. Finally the only thing that fixed this was creating a new service account.

I use both Windows and Debian-based Linux, this problem is not specific to the environment.
Also I use my JSON key both in Python and PHP.